# How to publish batch SNS messages using the AWS SDK for Java V2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Can anyone share a sample to publish messages to SNS in **batch** using AWS SDK 2.X.
The example that is on AWS website and other websites is a 1.X example. Looks like the batch publish service is not working with 2.x version.

// Create the batch entries to send
List entries = IntStream.range(0, MAX_BATCH_SIZE)
.mapToObj(i -> new PublishBatchRequestEntry()
.withId("id" + i)
.withMessage(payload.get(i)))
.collect(Collectors.toList());

```
        // Create the batch request
        PublishBatchRequest request = new PublishBatchRequest()
                .withTopicArn(BossEventsApplication.OUTPUT_TOPIC)
                .withPublishBatchRequestEntries(entries);

        // Publish the batch request
        PublishBatchResult publishBatchResult = snsClientV1.publishBatch(request);

        // Handle the successfully sent messages
        publishBatchResult.getSuccessful().forEach(publishBatchResultEntry -> {
            System.out.println("Batch Id for successful message: " + publishBatchResultEntry.getId());
            System.out.println("Message Id for successful message: " + publishBatchResultEntry.getMessageId());
        });

        // Handle the failed messages
        publishBatchResult.getFailed().forEach(batchResultErrorEntry -> {
            System.out.println("Batch Id for failed message: " + batchResultErrorEntry.getId());
            System.out.println("Error Code for failed message: " + batchResultErrorEntry.getCode());
            System.out.println("Sender Fault for failed message: " + batchResultErrorEntry.getSenderFault());
            System.out.println("Failure Message for failed message: " + batchResultErrorEntry.getMessage());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The **AWS SDk for Java V2** supports this functionality.  See -
https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sns/SnsClient.html#publishBatch(software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.PublishBatchRequest)

To publish batch messages, you need to create a List of **PublishBatchRequestEntry** objects.

Each **PublishBatchRequestEntry** object in the list has an **id** and **message** that represents the message. You can publish up to ten messages to the specified topic.

Here is a Java V2 code example that publishes batch messages to a standard topic.

```
package com.example.sns;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.PublishBatchRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.PublishBatchRequestEntry;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.SnsException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PublishBatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage: " +
            "   topicArn>\n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
           "   topicArn - The ARN of the topic to publish.\n\n";

        String topicArn = "<ENTER TOPIC ARN>";
        SnsClient snsClient = SnsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();
        pubBatchMessages(snsClient, topicArn) ;
        snsClient.close();
    }

    public static void pubBatchMessages(SnsClient snsClient, String topicArn) {
        try {
            PublishBatchRequestEntry publishBatchRequestEntry1 = PublishBatchRequestEntry.builder()
                .id("message100")
                .message("This is message 1")
                .build();

            PublishBatchRequestEntry publishBatchRequestEntry2 = PublishBatchRequestEntry.builder()
                .id("message200")
                .message("This is message 2")
                 .build();

            PublishBatchRequestEntry publishBatchRequestEntry3 = PublishBatchRequestEntry.builder()
                .id("message300")
                .message("This is message 3")
                .build();

            List<PublishBatchRequestEntry> pubList = new ArrayList<>();
            pubList.add(publishBatchRequestEntry1);
            pubList.add(publishBatchRequestEntry2);
            pubList.add(publishBatchRequestEntry3);

            PublishBatchRequest batchRequest = PublishBatchRequest.builder()
                .topicArn(topicArn)
                .publishBatchRequestEntries(pubList)
                .build();

            snsClient.publishBatch(batchRequest);
            System.out.println("The messages were successfully published");

        } catch (SnsException e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The lastest SNS Code examples can  be found in Code library. This example will be added soon. The URL IS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/sns_code_examples_actions.html

Comment: Thankyou . I will wait for the batch publish sample to be added to the list in V2.

Comment: Did this code work for you?  Make sure when you run it - to replace the value of topicArn with a valid ARN of a standard topic.

Comment: will test and share the results this week. Thankyou for the example.

Comment: Besure to use the SNS POM here https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/sns